# Change Hadoop IP address in VMware

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

I recently installed Hadoop (Hadoop sandbox 2.2 [Hortonworks]) with VMware in Windows 7. When Hadoop runs, it gives me an IP address for the web browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

It doesn't work. What address should I use, and how would I find it?

Comment: Are you using VMware image ? If yes, which distribution you are using?

Comment: i am using hortonworks hadoop sandbox 2.2 for vmware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the sandbox using VMware player. Type `ifconfig` in terminal.
You will get a `IP` address starting with `192.168.XX.XXX`. Replace `127.0.0.1` with that `IP` address. It will work.

**FYI:**

VMware player provides a dedicated IP to the sandbox and their guest OS, therefore all hadoop services is accessible through the `guest OS IP address`,not through your local host.